# Job not getting requested memory

Tags: slurm

I have a Slurm job `expensive` that is killed due to an out of memory error:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
slurmstepd: error: Detected 2 oom-kill event(s) in step expensive.batch cgroup. Some of your processes may have been killed by the cgroup out-of-memory handler.
```

The job is defined as:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name="expensive"
#SBATCH --mem=64G
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:rtx2080ti:6
#SBATCH --time=05:00:00
#SBATCH --partition=cpu-part

python expensive.py
```

It is clearly stated that the job requests 64 GB of RAM. When I run `sacct -j {jobid} -o JobID,JobName,MaxRSS,AveRSS,CPUTime` to profile it the output is:

```
       JobID    JobName     MaxRSS     AveRSS    CPUTime 
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- 
{jobid}       expensive                         00:04:01 
{jobid}.bat+      batch  21124408K  21124408K   00:04:01
```

It basically just ran 4 minutes, consumed about 20GB of ram and then crashed due to OOM. What am I missing here?